# Wordpress php excerpt not working - v simple

Tags: php, wordpress

First post on here and it's something I can't possibly find an answer to without a direct question. I am assuming this will be easy to answer to people who understand what they are looking at.

I have an excerpt in my theme but it isn't working. By this I mean it is showing the excerpt but it is not cutting the word length at all, it just shows the whole thing.

Code that creates the excerpt in functions:

```
Custom excerpt and more link


function ts_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    $ts_more = '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="btn">'. apply_filters('ts_more_text', __('Mas info', TS_DOMAIN)) .'</a>';
    return apply_filters('ts_more', $ts_more);
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'ts_excerpt_more');

function ts_the_excerpt($length = 55, $post_id = '', $more = ''){

    global $post, $more;

    if(!empty($post_id)) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $more = false;
    }

    // respect excerpt_length filter
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $length);

    $ts_more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">['. apply_filters('ts_more_text', __('More info', TS_DOMAIN)) .'&hellip;]</a>';

    // when excerpt comes with custom more, set it
    // else use the default excerpt more
    $excerpt_more = (!empty($more)) ? $more : apply_filters('excerpt_more', $ts_more);

    if (strpos($post->post_content, '<!--more-->')) {

        $output = get_the_content('', true);

    } else {

        if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {   

            $output = $post->post_excerpt;

        } else {

            $content = strip_tags($post->post_content); 
            preg_match('/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,' . $excerpt_length . '}/', $content, $matches);     
            $output = $matches[0];

        }

    }

    $output = strip_shortcodes($output);
    $output = wpautop($output).wpautop($excerpt_more);

    echo $output;
}
```

Here is the excerpt in the page:

```
<?php ts_the_excerpt(25, get_the_ID()); ?>
```

Literally have no idea, I can only assume the 25 is a word limit but this isn't working, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this with much less code and more control.

Try putting this in your functions.php file

```
function limit_excerpt_length($string, $word_limit)
{
$words = explode(' ', $string);

return implode( ' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit) );

}
```

Put this in your theme files where you want to limit the excerpt. 13 is the word count

```
    <?php echo limit_excerpt_length(get_the_excerpt(),  '13'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately this is causing problems in other files where the excerpt is used in an if loop:
'
<?php
        endif;
        // get teaser text
     ts_the_excerpt(25, get_the_ID());
       ?>
      
      </div><!-- end post -->
   
   <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
  
  </div>
  
  <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
  
  endif;
    }
'
I changed the 'ts_the_excerpt(25, get_the_ID());' to 'limit_excerpt_length(get_the_excerpt(),  '13');' but it still didn't work.

Comment: Ok I have realised that the excerpt that isnt working is here:

'<?php    
     endif;
     
     // get teaser text
     ts_the_excerpt(25, get_the_ID());     
    ?>
      
      </div><!-- end post -->
   
   <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
  
  </div>
  
  <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
  
  endif;
    }
'

Don't know if this makes it any easier..